# PHP - what is diff between date_timestamp_get(date_create()) and time()?

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

Both of those code are generate the same timestamp, so what their diff??

Does it affect the speed of processing??

```
echo date_timestamp_get(date_create()); // e.g. 1478854173
echo time(); // e.g. 1478854173
```

And does it depend on the local time of user? Or depends on the local time of server?

Comment: The difference is, they both have separate docs [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php), [2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) to read through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the first approach is using two function calls, while the second is done with just one call. So theoretically using just `time()` should be faster ... in a matter of microseconds or less.

The only benefit of the first approach is that you can pass whatever date you want to `date_create()` and get its timestamp like this:

```
date_timestamp_get(date_create('2016-12-12 12:00:00'));
```

while `time()` returns you the current timestamp.

Comment: And does it depend on the local time of user? Or depends on the local time of server?

Comment: It depends on server time.